# Ошибка в скрипте

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть скрипт:

```
    <?php

if (!defined('DATALIFEENGINE')) {
    die('Доступ ограничен!');
}

$users = dle_cache('procore_users', $config['skin']);

if (!$users) {
    $row = $db->super_query('SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM '.PREFIX.'_users');
    $users = '<span class="red">'.$row['count'].'</span>';
    create_cache('procore_users', $users, $config['skin']);
}

function declOfNum($num, $titles) {
    $cases = array (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
    return $num." ".$titles[($num%100>4 && $num%100<20)? 2 : $cases[min($num%10, 5)]];
}

echo declOfNum($users, array('юзер', 'юзера', 'юзеров'));

?>
```

На сайте выдает ошибку:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare
> declOfNum() (previously declared in
> /home/m17275/public_html/site.ru/engine/modules/all_users.php:15)
> in
> /home/m17275/public_html/site.ru/engine/modules/all_users.php
> on line 18

Подскажите, как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Фатальная ошибка: Невозможно переопределить функцию declOfNum().

У Вас

```
function declOfNum($num, $titles) {
}
```

где-то уже объявлена, возможно, в другом файле, который Вы инклудите.

Comment: переименовал функцию, изменений не произошло

Comment: all_users.php - это и есть этот код

Comment: @malcov значит файл подгружается многократно

Comment: Точно, случайно грузил 2 раза. Большое спасибо!